# Multiple JQuery UI Autcomplete boxes - getting the value for the one that's selected

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got three jQuery UI 'Autocomplete' input fields on a page:

```
<select id="combobox1"><?php putSome1ValuesHere(); ?></select>
<select id="combobox2"><?php putSome2ValuesHere(); ?></select>
<select id="combobox3"><?php putSome3ValuesHere(); ?></select>
```

And making them all into comboboxes works fine:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#combobox1" ).combobox();
    $( "#combobox2" ).combobox();
    $( "#combobox3" ).combobox();
});
```

What I'd like to do is redirect to another page, based on the value chosen in combo boxes. This works fine if I name one of the boxes explicity:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    that._trigger( "selected", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
    window.location.href = $('#combobox1').val() + ".php";
},
```

What I can't do is make it redirect based on the value of whichever combo-box has been clicked. I can't hard-wire it because any one of the three boxes could be clicked. However, I just don't know enough about jQuery to access the value of the box which has called the 'select' function. I'd be grateful for any advice anyone could provide. I think I've included enough info above, but if anything is needed then please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the combobox widget code `select` is the jQuery object for select tag that has been hidden

```
window.location.href = select.val() + ".php";
```

DEMO using `select.val()` http://jsfiddle.net/YBFAr/

Comment: Thanks - when I try this I just get: array(1) { ["areaID"]=> string(0) "" }     dumped to screen and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, that will teach me to reply in a hurry! The bit above is my PHP going wonky because there's still no value being passed to it using $(this).val(). I've tried setting an alert() to show the value of $9this).val() and it just comes up as 'undefined'.

Comment: where does `combobox` plugin come from? link?

Comment: It's part of jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox   Sometimes that link just shows the default demo for me in Safari, but there is a link for a 'combobox' demo in the menu on the right-hand side. Also includes the rest of the code I've used as the basis for my page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
  ui.item.option.selected = true;
  that._trigger( "selected", event, {
      item: ui.item.option
 });
 window.location.href = $('#combobox1').val() + ".php";
},
```

to

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    that._trigger( "selected", event, {
    item: ui.item.option
    });
    window.location.href = $(this).val() + ".php";
},
```

Hope this helps